# Issue with Deploying Vue.js + Node + MySQL + NginX app @DigitalOcean

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nginx, digital-ocean

I have set up Ubuntu droplet with UFW, MySQL, Node, Vue-Cli, and NginX.

I have created an “apps” folder inside “html”

> /var/www/html/apps/

apps folder contains two folders:

/var/www/html/apps/codnode
/var/www/html/apps/codvue

Inside `codvue` folder, I cloned the Vue app
and for `codnode` folder, I cloned the node api (uses port 3001)

Here are NginX server blocks (or whatever they are called) settings.

Default server config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html/apps/codvue/dist;

       # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;
        error_page 404 /;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}
```

Created another server block named node:

```
server {
        listen 81 default_server;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name IPADDRESS;
        error_page 404 /;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

}
```

Both the Default and node are linked to sites-enabled…

The issue that I’m currently experiencing is:

When I go to `/var/www/html/apps/codvue/` and create a build using:

```
sudo npm run build
```

After restarting Nginx service, I open the website using the IP address, the interface of the app loads just fine (means Vue is working, correct?). Alongside I’m running the Node app in another terminal which says running at port 3001 and Db connection successful.

But other than the Vue interface no data is shown. front end working. Backend NOT Displaying. When I try to access this URL: `http://IPADDRESS:81/Api/category/categories-list` it shows the data:

```
[{"catID":1,"catName":"sabdasdv1","catDesc":"qdjqbwd","isActive":"1","date":....
```

Now I go back to /var/www/html/apps/codvue/ and execute the following command:

```
sudo npm run serve
```

The app is served on port 8080. When I open the `http://IPADDRESS:8080`, the app loads just fine… Both the interface and the data is there.

Can someone please guide me on how can I get the build version to work? What am I doing wrong here?

Below is the Vue config file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    // outputDir :path.resolve(__dirname, '../server/public'),
    devServer:{
        proxy:{
            '/api':{
                target: 'http://IPADDRESS:81'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that I’m missing a very small but important piece of this puzzle to make this thing work with Vue’s Build version.

Any sort of help will be highly appreciated. Thank you for your time in reading it to the end.

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you put the request the frontend is doing? the path it is requesting?

Comment: @Danizavtz Front end is working mean Vue's routes are fine, correct? However, when it fetches data from API it does not bring in the data in Build version `sudo npm run build`, but works fine when I `sudo npm run serve` it @8080.

Comment: Yes I would like to see some chrome dev tools network tab, to try to figure out the route it is requesting, if there is any hint of what could be the problem. Lets say some appended or missing string in path. So we can make a mapping to the correct route.

Comment: Can you test the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try a different configuration.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html/apps/codvue/dist;

       # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;
        error_page 404 /;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        location /api {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Please comment the block with configuration with server on port `81` (whole file).

After make the configuration, test the configuration to check if there is syntax errors:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

If everything ok, output should be:

> nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
>   nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Then restart your nginx with:

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

Cache clean your browser and try again.

Comment: Commented out the port 81 file as a whole... added /Api location to port 80 file... Same behavior, Fron end loads, but tables are not being populated with data. However, data is accessible from http://ip/Api...
However, npm run serve @8080 is no more working
Also, has to change vue config file from port 81 to 80

Comment: I will fix that in the answer, sorry.

Comment: Finally, found the issue.And it's a silly one :| "Api" was the culprit :| in the config file it was api while in NginX, it was "Api" with initicap.
Thanks for making my Nginx  file more compact and thank you for your time and guide

Comment: Oh, so you have diagnosed the error while I was typing ... thank you very much! :)

Comment: Congratulations,  you did it! I will try to remove the comments with sensible data.